# Controls spill over to next page in RDLC Report

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2008r2-express

Problem no 1 (refer pics): When the horizontal tablix expands at runtime, controls which are positioned after the tablix get pushed to the next page.
Problem no 2 (refer pics): How to get vertical lines to expand at runtime? (the endpoints of these lines are tagged to the expanding rectangle. The rectangle expands but the lines do not)

Pics:

- Design time

[image: Design time]

- Runtime

[image: Runtime]

What I have done till now:

1. KeepTogether = false for all rectangles and all textboxes and all tables (basically all controls on the RDLC)
2. Report page size is 8.27in, 11.69in (std A4 size)
3. Recreated the entire report again
4. Reduced margins to 0.5in on all sides
5. When I make the starting point (Properties - Location - Left) of these controls the same as the culprit control (refer design time pic), they do not shift anymore. But that's not where I want them to be

I am using:
VS 2015, .Net 4.5.2, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, SSDT 2015, Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. Displaying reports using ReportViewer

Comment: Please add all necessary information to your question, rather than linking to external media.

Comment: Have you tried reducing your margins?

Comment: What if you wrap the whole layout in a rectangle?

Comment: Hi @Harry. Brilliant idea, but it didnt work. Appreciate it though. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Hi @StevenWhite. Tried it after you suggested. Margins are reduced to 0.5in from 1in all over. Yet, the problem remains. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Hi @iamdave. It can be explained only in pictures as it is related to the report layout. You will understand when you see the pdf. There is no provision to upload a pdf here and a single picture is not enough to explain the problem.

Comment: @PrasadKamath  You will see on other questions that multiple pictures can be uploaded and embedded in your question.  PDFs are a notoriously dangerous file format to be opening from unknown sources so you will receive less help.

Comment: @iamdave. Made the changes as suggested. Kindly check and provide a solution if you can.

Comment: @PrasadKamath This is going to invoice a bit of redesign- This has worked for me in the past.. place a List box on your designer window.. Add a ROW GROUP- assuming this report is grouped on employee. Then remove the detailed group and the row. Now expand the list box as big as you want and place a tablix inside the list box. Now you have a grouped table control. You can add as many rows and columns as you need and adjust / merge each row and column and it's borders as you need. This should stop who sections from jumping to a new page. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you have multiple items all sharing the same 'report space' and can therefore interact with each other.  By default, SSRS will push any items around others that can grow, such as tables.

This happens where a report item's top left corner is to the right of or below the item that can grow.  In your case, this is because the textboxes that are moving are to the right of your culprit table.  You will notice that the text boxes that start before the end of your table are unaffected.

To stop this from happening, you need to tell SSRS that you don't want these items to be interfered with by the table, by putting then in a different 'report space'.  What this means in the designer, is that you need to put the textboxes in a rectangle that starts before the end of the table.

Create one rectangle at the top and one at the bottom of your report that is tall enough to hold both textboxes and that spans the entire report width, then add the textboxes that are being moved to the rectangle using drag and drop.

---

To expand your lines in the middle of your report, don't use lines at all.  Put a border on the right hand side of the matrix column that is returning the `SALNAME` value.

Comment: yes it worked, thanks!  @Harry - I tried iamdave's suggestion and it worked, so didn't try your method, but thanks a lot for your response. Thank you all for your responses. case closed.

Comment: @PrasadKamath  No worries.  If this was the correct answer to your question, for the benefit of others with the same issue, kindly mark it as such.